# Is there a way to define a variable that is a parameter inside a function in Python?

Tags: python, function, variables, printing, parameters

Is it possible to define a variable that is a parameter inside a function?
I've tried doing this:

```
def myfunc(variable):
    variable = 5


myfunc(x)
print(x)
```

I was expecting to see the number "5" printed on my screen, because I'm defining x (which is 5) and then printing it.
But I get this NameError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yoelc\PycharmProjects\Test\app.py", line 4, in <module>
    myfunc(x)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

I know it is possible to do this:

```
def myfunc():
    return 5


x = myfunc()
print(x)
```

But that's not what I'm trying to do.
Is there a way to define this?

Comment: do you want to redefine your variable from outer scope inside a function?

Comment: In short: no, not in any sane way. Don’t try to introduce this kind of magic into your code, since it’s at the very least extremely unorthodox and will lead to confusion and bugs.

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe not exactly what you want but pretty similar:

```
def myfunc(variable):
    globals()[variable] = 5
myfunc('x')
print(x)
```

That being said this is a bad idea, unless you really need to use metaprogramming for some reason